# Cannot get to ObjectTrackingEnabled linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have had a problem where it appeared as though the second execution of a stored procedure was being ignored.

The first time I call my stored procedure it found 20 records and extracted information for the date range August 2009.  The first line was meter id 233 with a data value 200

I then called the stored procedure and 20 records were also returned.  This time meter id 233 had a data value of 300.

Linq is detecting that meterid 233 already exists in the context and so doesnt update

I am sure this is something to do with ObjectTrackingEnabled but this does not seem to be available for me to set to false?

I didnt write the context code so I dont really know how it all works, but I have noticed that it seems to inherit from ObjectDataContext

This was generate using Entity Framework and VS 2008

namespace DataServiceDAL
{

```
/// <summary>
/// There are no comments for dbChildDataContext in the schema.
/// </summary>
public partial class dbChildDataContext : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new dbChildDataContext object using the connection string found in the 'dbChildDataContext' section of the application configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    public dbChildDataContext() : 
            base("name=dbChildDataContext", "dbChildDataContext")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();            
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new dbChildDataContext object.
    /// </summary>
    public dbChildDataContext(string connectionString) : 
            base(connectionString, "dbChildDataContext")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new dbChildDataContext object.
    /// </summary>
    public dbChildDataContext(global::System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, "dbChildDataContext")
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
    partial void OnContextCreated();
```

..............
}

I use the following linq to extract the data

```
    public static List<MeterTotalConsumpRecord> GetTotalAllTimesConsumption(DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtEnd, EUtilityGroup ug, int nMeterSelectionType, int nCustomerID, 
        int nUserID, string strSelection, bool bClosedLocations, bool bDisposedLocations)
    {    
        dbChildDataContext db = DBManager.ChildDataConext(nCustomerID);

        var tbl = from t in db.GetTotalConsumptionByMeter(dtStart, dtEnd, (int) ug, nMeterSelectionType, nCustomerID, nUserID, strSelection, bClosedLocations, bDisposedLocations, 1)                       
                  select t;                        

        return tbl.ToList();            
    }
```

I need a way of clearing this cache out so that the objects are updated properly or I need a way of refreshing the objects

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend you to refresh objects using [MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx).
Here is a simple example:

```
var query = from d in context.Depts
                   where d.Deptno < 50
                   select d;
(query as ObjectQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately I cannot test if this works because of the other problem I am getting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227685/query-results-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once do you have any ideas for that one?

Comment: Hi when I try this (query as ObjectQuery) is null

Any ideas?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Maybe you should try to use Entity SQL instead in this particular case. The reason is described here in Julie Lerman's blog:
http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/querying-with-linq-to-entities-vs-objectquery-in-ef/

Comment: How would I change my code to use Entity SQL Devart?  I dont really understand that link

Comment: var query = new ObjectQuery<Dept>("select value dept from Depts as dept where dept.Deptno < 50", context);
(query as ObjectQuery).MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;